# Jquery multiselect event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html dropdown.  I want to fire an event whenever the selection changes in any way.  I tried registering a 'click' event but this didnt work when multi-selecting (either by dragging the mouse or holding down shift + down arrow).

So basically, how can I fire an event on *any* selection change?

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/D92z7/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the `onchange` event.

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Would .change() do the trick?

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Certainly there seems to be a working demo of a multi-select box on that page...

Answer (score 0):

jquery 1.4:  `$("#mySelector").change(myChangeEvent);`
before:  `$("#mySelector").bind("change", myChangeEvent);`

```
function myChangeEvent(e){

}
```