# Multiselect refresh callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I use Multiselect jQuery plugin for my dropdowns. I have a requirement where in i refresh the dropdown setting some value as true. It takes a while for it to refresh. This is not an issue considering the content in the dropdown. but i want to know if there is a way to know if the refresh is completely done or not, something like a callback after refresh.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492042/jquery-multiselect-event-handler possibly? First google result for "jquery-multiselect on change"

Comment: Please post your code! Let us know what you have done??